# Not working yet when trying to report progress from a class to form1 backgroundworker. What could be that make the program hang?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The problem is when i'm running the program and put a break point in the class on the line:

```
ProgressChanged?.DynamicInvoke(new ProgressEventArgs{ Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc });
```

It stop on this line but then i make continue it's not getting there anymore and the program just hang does nothing. I'm not getting any exceptions.

In the class:

```
public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public int Percentage { get; set; }
            public string StateText { get; set; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

        public void Init()
        {
            int index = 0;
            ExtractCountires();
            foreach (string cc in countriescodes)
            {
                // raise event here
                ProgressChanged?.DynamicInvoke(new ProgressEventArgs{ Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc });
                ExtractDateAndTime("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + cc);
                index++;
            }
            ImagesLinks();
        }
```

In Form1 constructor:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

In Form1 backgroundworker events:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return; // this will fall to the finally and close everything    
            }
            else
            {
                ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();
                ei.ProgressChanged += (senders, eee) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(eee.Percentage, e);
                ei.Init();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

Some changed i needed to do or else i got errors:

In the class on the line:

```
ProgressChanged?.DynamicInvoke(new ProgressEventArgs{ Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc });
```

It was ProgressChanged?.Invoke but i got error on the Invoke only when i changed it to DynamicInvoke i got no error.

In Form1:

On the line:

```
ei.ProgressChanged += (senders, eee) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(eee.Percentage, e);
```

It was sender, e but since sender and e already exist in the event i had to change it to senders and eee.

Comment: if you know all types at design time - and this is the case here - you should use Invoke. focus on that error you said you got while using Invoke.

Comment: The error when using Inovke is: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'EventHandler<ExtractImages.ProgressEventArgs>.Invoke(object, ExtractImages.ProgressEventArgs)'

Comment: It's almost working fine if i add the line: object obj = null; then add the obj variable in the line with the Invoke: ProgressChanged?.Invoke(obj,new ProgressEventArgs{ Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc }); but then the progressBar1 in form1 is not getting to the end it stop a bit before the end about 90-95% .

Comment: I also see now i can't get the StateText from the class. In the class i did: ProgressChanged?.Invoke(obj,new ProgressEventArgs{ Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc }); and then in the form1 dowork event: ei.ProgressChanged += (senders, eee) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(eee.Percentage, eee); and then in the progresschanged event: label7.Text = e.UserState.ToString(); but it's not showing the cc in the label7 but ProgressEventArgs

Comment: Ok i solved the problem with the StateText it's now working. And ichecked it against the List in the class it does get to the end to the last StateText (cc). But the programmBar1 is not getting to 100% but to 90-95%. Should i add in the completed event: progressBar1.Value = 100; Or it's something wrong with the calculation i did in the class ?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with the debugger.  Try this [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/). I know the debugger hangs a lot in different scenarios and can be fixes through your settings **VS > Tools > Options > Debugging**.

Please read up on the different options if you don't know exactly what they do.

Comment: The error i'm getting when using Invoke is: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'EventHandler<ExtractImages.ProgressEventArgs>.Invoke(object, ExtractImages.ProgressEventArgs)' I will also look in the link you have provided.